# Confirmation box to Yii button

Tags: yii

I made a button in my site and it executes a script in my CentOS, but I'm looking for a solution to put a confirmation box to execute the action.
The button:

```
$attribs[] = array(
    'label' => Yii::t('mc', 'Instalar Technic -> B Team'),  
    'type' => 'raw', 
    'cssClass' => 'mpack',
    'value' => CHtml::ajaxButton(
        Yii::t('mc', 'Instalar B Team'), 
        '', 
        array(
       'type' => 'POST',
       'data' => array(
           'ajax' => 'bteam', 
           Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName=>Yii::app()->request->csrfToken,),
           'success' => 'function(e) {
                if (e) alert(e);
           }'
        ),
        array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm')),
        'hint' => Yii::t('mc', 'Servidor n&atilde;o liga? Este bot&atilde;o seta "true" na "eula.txt", &eacute; necessario isso para seu servidor ligar, cheque seu console para verifica&ccedil;&atilde;o.'),
        //Edit the hint option here 
);
```

Comment: The English is not a problem, have you looked on the format of your code however?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a confirmation box simply declaring the proper data-confimr in your link

```
'value' => CHtml::ajaxButton(
    Yii::t('mc', 'Instalar B Team'), 
    '', 
    array(
   'type' => 'POST',
   'data' => array(
       'ajax' => 'bteam', 
          Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName=>Yii::app()->request->csrfToken,),
       'success' => 'function(e) {
            if (e) alert(e);
       }'
    ),
    array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm', 
           'confirm' => "do you want confirm this action ?" ),

    ));
```

Comment: Could be the data-confirm is in the wrong place.. I have update the answer. moving data.confirm in htmlOptions and not inside ajax

Comment: Please can you post the result html code for the CHtml::ajaxButton ? . I want see what is generated by the CHtml helper..

Comment: Worked: I Used this          ), array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
  'confirm' => 'Are you sure you\'d like to submit this action?',
)),

Comment: Thanks for the help Scais!

Comment: I update the answer with you add. If you have find my answer useful please rate it and/or mark as accepted ..